# Java script function not executed in jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have included my user-defined javascript functions into the layout.jade, which looks like this:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='../public/javascript/myjavascript.js')
  body
    block content
```

Now if I include a function from myjavascript.js in index.js, it is not executed, even though the call is present in the resulting html. The code of index.jade:

```
extends layout 
block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    script(type='text/javascript').
            alerting();
```

The code of myjavascript.js:

```
function alerting(){
    alert("working");
    console.log("myjavascript called");
}
```

The resulting rendered html:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/myjavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript">alerting();</script> 
...
```

However if I include javascript inline in the jade template, the function gets called, i.e. the following code displays an alert window:

```
extends layout
block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    script(type='text/javascript').
        alert("My alert");
```

Can you please point out, where I made a mistake?

Comment: Can you link your javascript? It's most likely a scoping problem. Prolly know when we see how the ```alerting()``` function is declared.

Comment: check inspect element in chrome, your src link looks strange. Does it link ok ?

Comment: Oh sorry guys, I just made a mistake in my link. I should be javascripts not javascript. Still your comments led me to where to look :-), it works now.